# Shift TD border-left to the right a bit

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this html:

```css
tr,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.none {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>header 1</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td>subheading1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td style='padding-left:50px'>
      text for subheading1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the TD with the text `text for subheading1` to have its left border starting a bit to the right. How do I do this with CSS? I tried giving its margin some negative values but that had no effect.

[image]

I'd like its left border to start where I've drawn a line in this image. Is that possible?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmmxzbv/)

Comment: Bascically, you can't. Borders go **around** elements,..ans margins don't affect table-cells. I'd suggest you restructure....

Comment: @Paulie_D hmm, thanks, but do you think there's another way to do what I want then?

Comment: Don't use a table...it doesn't look like this is tabluar data anyway.

Comment: @Paulie_D you're right, but this is for a really quick and simple internal thing so I thought a table would be quickest to make!

Comment: ...and now you've discovered why speed isn't necessarily better. A simple list & sublist would be just as quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `display` to **block** on that cell and then you can use `margin-left`

```css
tr,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.none {
  border: none;
}
.target {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>header 1</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td>subheading1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td class="target">
      text for subheading1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah! That's clever! :D Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Here You have the code

```css
tr,
td {
  padding: 10px;
   width:230px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td.none {
  border: none;
}
.this{
  margin-left:50px;
  position:absolute;
  width:140px;

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>header 1</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td>subheading1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'></td>
    <td class='this' style='padding-left:50px'>
      text for subheading1
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```